# Eigenvalues of Gauss-Seidel Iteration Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Consider the (tridiagonal) matrix $$A^h=\frac{1}{h^2}\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
> -1 & 2 & -1 & \dots & 0\\
> & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
> & & & -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times(n-1)}$$
>   Assume that $B_{GS}=I-(M_{GS})^{-1}A^h$, where $M_{GS}=D-L$, where $D$ is the diagonal of $A^h$ and $L$ the lower part. Give an analytical expression of the eigenvalues of $B_{GS}$.

I don't quite understand how to get to the answer. So far, I've found that:
$$B_{GS}=-(L+D)^{-1}U$$
So in order to find the eigenvalues, we ought to solve:
$$-(L+D)^{-1}U\vec{x}=\lambda\vec{x}$$
I have also found that the smallest eigenvalue, say $\lambda_0=0$ because the first column is entirely $0$. Could anyone prove me a hint to continue?

**Edit:**
$B_{GS}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\
0 & 2^{-(n-1)} & 2^{-(n+2)} & \dots & \frac{1}{4} \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Have you already tried looking at what $B_{GS}$ looks like when written out explicitly?

Comment: I did, I put that matrix in the question

Comment: Maybe this helps: As $A$ symmetric and positive definite it holds $\text{spr}(J)^2 = \text{spr}(B_{GS})$ with the Jacobi-Matrix $J=-D^{-1}(L+R)$.

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Oh and you matrix is nothing else but the finite difference matrix of the PDE $u''=f$. The same matrix can be derived by using a specific FEM and Integrator combination. So maybe [this](https://math.la.asu.edu/~gardner/iter.pdf), will help as well.

Comment: @Holograph did you ever get the full answer? I am running into the exact same issue.